# Calling a Controller Method in a View - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel-blade

I want to make a method in my Controller that I can call in my view and supply a foreach statement inside my view.

```
  {{!! $product_coupon_controller = new Product_coupon();
   //  $categories = $product_coupon_controller->categories(); 
!!}}
```

Although when I call this, I get an error that the class does not exist.

I am using Blade Templating.

Comment: calling controller method from view is not good practice . what is the purpose to call ?

Comment: This is not how MVC works. Everything has to pass through the controller. Your view should only display data not process it.